# Is there a keyboard shortcut to navigate one level up in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

On Windows, pressing Backspace in Explorer will navigate to the parent folder in the Explorer window. Is there an equivalent keyboard shortcut for Finder on macOS?

Comment: Have a look at the **Finder shortcuts** _section_ in: [Mac keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)

Comment: By the way, Backspace in the Windows Explorer will go back to the previous folder you were in (which may or may not be the parent folder). Alt+↑ is for going up one level.

Comment: I have an AppleTV and iPhone and am thinking of buying my first Mac. Thing is, I navigate one level up in Windows all the time. I see you didn't accept Monomeeth's answer, does that mean it's wrong? Did you ever find the answer?

Answer (score 202):

The one you're probably looking for is the <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>⬆︎</kbd> keyboard shortcut, as this is the one that takes you back to the *parent* folder.

To do the same thing, but within a **new** window, use <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>control</kbd> <kbd>⬆︎</kbd>.

However, some views offer additional options. For example, in Columns view you can just use the <kbd>⬅︎</kbd> key to go back to the *parent* folder.

In addition, you can use the <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd> keyboard shortcut to take you back to the previous folder you were actually in (which may not necessarily be the parent folder).

You can also right-click on the title in the Finder's window to select anywhere in the file's path to go straight to that location.

Finally, you can also customise the Toolbar to add the Path button.

Comment: Slightly related tip: usually when I want to navigate to my home folder, I just click on my desktop (= focus sets to Finder) and press cmd+up. This works because your desktop’s parent folder is your home folder.

Comment: I guess the folks at Apple have decided there should be no Up button ever.

Comment: @Stephane  Maybe there isn't an "Up" button, but every Finder view has a "columns view" button which reveals the full folder hierarchy.  No, its not the same as a single-click button... and it is not at all obvious to a new user, but it does facilitate the same functionality as an "Up" button without using keyboard shortcuts.